# Hide folder in path using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to hide the folder called `contents` in the URL path http://example.com/contents/folder-1/

My folder structure looks like:

```
/
--contents/
----folder-1/
------index.php
----folder-2/
------index.php
----folder-3/
------index.php
index.php
```

I have full root access to the server, enabled a2enmod rewrite, restarted apache. I then put the following .htaccess file in the / directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+contents/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^contents/)^(.*)$ /contents/$1 [L,NC]
```

However, when I go to http://example.com/folder-1/ it just gives me a 404 page error.